# QT6 How to convert QVideoFrame to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, qimage, qt6

Does anyone know how to convert `QVideoFrame` to `OpenCV cv::Mat` in QT6?
I have event where video frame arrived from video camera.

```
void videoFrameChanged(const QVideoFrame &frame)// frame from QCamera
{
  QImage qImg=frame.toImage();//<<-- slow
   cv::Mat m=Qimage2Mat_shared(qImg);

  ...
}
```

I know how to convert QImage to cv::Mat, but here used very slow function: frame.toImage().
How to convert directly QVideoFrame to cv::Mat ?

Comment: based on image format you can avoid ```toImage()``` function. e.g. ```cv::Mat mat(frame.height(), frame.width(), CV_8UC3, frame.bits(),frame.bytesPerLine());```

Comment: @Roshan M, frame.bits() and frame.bytesPerLine() request parameter 'plane'. QT6 used not QT5